# Dynamic rewrite rules with glob patterns in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a URL structure to a "project detail" page that looks like this: `john/project/eRdKn6` (where "john" is the username and "eRdKn6" is the project id). I want this to be rewritten to the file `project.html`, where I parse the document.location and load the appropriate data. So the username and the project id should be dynamic.

The rule in `firebase.json` that I have looks like this:

```
{
  "source": "*/project/*",
  "destination": "/project.html"
}
```

However, Firebase 404's when I try to load `http://example.com/john/project/eRdKn6`.

I've tried to make only the last part dynamic, as a test (e.g. `{"source": "john/project/*", "destination": "/project.html"}` but I also get a 404.

The `project.html` is in the `public` folder.

Here is my full `firebase.json` file:

```
{
  "firebase": "example",
  "public": "public",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {"source": "*/project/*", "destination": "/project.html"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you read the [rewrite rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/url-redirects-rewrites.html#section-rewrites) guide and the associated link on [glob patterns](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/full-config.html#section-glob)? There are several examples, and none look like yours. Specifically, `**` instead of `*`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to follow the guide but it didn't cover my use case. Your comment helped solve it, though: `**/project/**` seemed to work, which caused me to dig deeper. (The [glob docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/full-config.html#section-glob) mention that `**` matches any file or folder in an arbitrary sub-directory, which is not what I wanted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the issue is that `source` requires a starting slash, e.g. `/*/project/*`. My full `firebase.json` now looks like this:

```
{
  "firebase": "example",
  "public": "public",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "rewrites": [
    {"source": "/*/project/*", "destination": "/project.html"}
  ]
}
```

This seems a documentation issue, since none of the examples cover this use case.